# Another jQuery Quicksand jumpy transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, quicksand

When I hit filter the li get a left overlapping position before to get in transition to filter. I tested the previous questions and answers but isn't solved the problem. The ul doesn't use an absolute position, the li class have left float.

here is the html

```
    <div class="filters">

        <ul id="filters" class="clearfix">
            <li><a title="all" href="#" class="active"> all </a></li>
            <li><a title="web" href="#"> web </a></li>
            <li><a title="app" href="#"> app </a></li>
            <li><a title="logo" href="#"> logo </a></li>
            <li><a title="card" href="#"> card </a></li>
            <li><a title="icon" href="#"> icon </a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="portfolio">

        <ul id="portfolio_list">

            <li class="portfolio" data-id="id-1" data-type="logo">
                <div class="portfolio-wrapper">             
                    <img src="images/portfolios/logo/5.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="label">
                        <div class="label-text">
                            <a class="text-title">Bird Document</a>
                            <span class="text-category">Logo</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="label-bg"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>               

            <li class="portfolio" data-id="id-2" data-type="app">
                <div class="portfolio-wrapper">         
                    <img src="images/portfolios/app/1.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="label">
                        <div class="label-text">
                            <a class="text-title">Visual Infography</a>
                            <span class="text-category">APP</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="label-bg"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
         </ul></div>
```

And this is the jQuery call

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $filter = $('#filters a');
    var $portfolio = $('#portfolio_list');
    var $data = $portfolio.clone();

    $filter.click(function(e) {

        if ($($(this)).attr("title") == 'all') {
            var $filteredData = $data.find('li');
        } else {
            var $filteredData = $data.find('li[data-type=' + $($(this)).attr("title") + ']');
        }

        $portfolio.quicksand($filteredData, {
            adjustHeight: 'dynamic',
            duration: 800,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
        });

        $('#filters a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

    });

});
```

forgot to post the css

```
#portfolio_list li { overflow:hidden; float: left; }
#portfolio_list .portfolio { width:19%; margin:2% 1% 0% 1%; border: 1px solid #c8c8a9; background: #fff; padding: 20px; }
    #portfolio_list .portfolio-wrapper { overflow:hidden; position: relative !important;    cursor:pointer; }
    #portfolio_list .portfolio img { max-width:100%; position: relative; }
    #portfolio_list .portfolio .label { position: absolute; width: 100%; height:50px; bottom:-50px; }
        #portfolio_list .portfolio .label-bg { background: #fff; width: 100%; height:100%; position: absolute; top:0; left:0; }
        #portfolio_list .portfolio .label-text { color:#000; position: relative;    z-index:500; padding:12px 8px 0; }
            #portfolio_list .portfolio .text-category { display:block; }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you put a fiddle for us to see?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was cause by same ID used to style the ul and li and in same time to call it with jQuery. Is needed to use an ID without css styles to not create glitches in quicksand.